# How to change gradient color of qr code image generated by python's module qr code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, gradient, qr-code

I am using python [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/) module

I am trying to change the gradient color of the qr image generated by this code:

```
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
            version=1,
            error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
            box_size=10,
            border=4,
        )
        qr.add_data("Some text")
        qr.make(fit=True)

self.img = qr.make_image(fill_color="White", back_color="Transparent", image_factory=StyledPilImage, module_drawer=RoundedModuleDrawer(), color_mask=RadialGradiantColorMask())
        self.img.show()
```

the piece of code `color_mask=RadialGradiantColorMask()` adds the gradient color to the qr code but I am unable to change the colors. Please help

Output using this code:
[Original Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isBBo.png)

I tired many things like `color_mask=((200,200,200))` but this changes the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the input to the RadialGradiantColorMask Class
when creating the object of the class as

```
color_mask=RadialGradiantColorMask(back_color=(XX,XX,XX),edge_color=(XX,XX,XX),center_color=(XX,XX,XX))
```

This should help you customize the colours.
Please refer to the [Git Page](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/main/qrcode/image/styles/colormasks.py) for further documentation